# Delete old files on MEGA using megatools

Tags: cloud, delete-file

How I can delete old ( for example older than 7 days ) files on MEGA using megatools?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This how I solve this problem in ubuntu.

1. I mount file system with the tools megafs.
2. One of the few thing you are allow to do is remove files.

MOUNTPOINT = /mnt/path/your/mounting/dir
MEGA_REMOTE_DIR = /Root/path/remote/dir/*

```
apt install megatools
megafs /mnt/path/your/mounting/dir 
find /mnt/path/your/mounting/dir/Root/path/mega/remote/dir/* -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
umount /mnt/path/your/mounting/dir
```

Maybe is posible other solutions using megals --long. Get the +7 days old  and remove with megarm.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: On MEGA using megatools !! Is your answer is about this question?

Comment: Yes is about this cuestion is my personal approach for delete my old backups from [MEGA] (https://mega.nz). I just benefit from, one of a  few thing you can do with you mount Mega fileisystem is remove files. Visite this  link to understand MEGA remote filesystem. https://megatools.megous.com/man/megatools.html

Comment: I have the same problem, just  install 1.9.97. If you install the last 1.9.98 megatools You can not find megafs because is inside test/tools. In 1.9.97 inside folder tools  you will megafs.c, apt install megatools in ubuntu install 1.9.97. I hope this can help you.